# How to modify permission of other installed apps on android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

How do I modify permission of other installed apps on android.

An app on I tired on play-store [AppOps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission) does this, wanted to understand the apis available in android to achieve the same.

Comment: hello friend .. care to explain the reason for down vote?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible, even with root access. An app can't change the permissions of another app even through the use of the device administration API.

Any app on the market that claims to do this is either lying, or re-packaging applications and signing them itself to create a new application.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be true since the device admin API seems to expose this capability
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPermissionGrantState(android.content.ComponentName, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)